# Android REST client stops on restTemplate.getForObject()

Tags: java, android, rest

Piece of my code:

```
final String url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
Currency currency = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Currency.class);
return currency;
```

My app stops when executing .getForObject() method. There is my Currency class:

```
public class Currency {
    private String base;
    private String date;
    private HashMap<String, Double> rates;

    // getters & setters
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Show your error Logcat info .

Comment: show your log for errors buddy

Comment: How can I do that? Application just hangs. I'm a newbie with Android Studio :/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hnzT2bgP
There are my logs when I go to the breakpoint with that method

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Added permissions in AndroidManifest and It seems to work.